# subtract every element of 1D numpy array with every other element of the same array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

consider the below array

```
np.array([a,b,c]) #where a,b and c are some integers
```

i with to do something like this

```
[(a-b),(a-c),(b-c)] #basically subtract each element in the array with every other element except for itself
```

this is somewhat like a matrix but there is no need to do something like `(a-a)` or repeat instance which are basically just the reverse like `(b - a) or (c - b)` is reverse of `(a - b) and (a - c)`

If this were a product there are some ready to use functions available like `np.kron` but how to handle non-product operations like this?

the closest i have got to is:

```
(a[0] - np.choose([1,2],a))
```

this basically give me `(a-b)` and `(a - c)` but still `(b - c)` remains. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get those pair-wise indices with[`triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)/`tril_indices` and then simply index and subtract. Thus, the implementation would be -

```
r,c = np.triu_indices(a.size,1) # Input array : a
out = a[r] - a[c]
```

Sample run -

```
In [159]: a = np.array([3,5,6])

In [160]: r,c = np.triu_indices(a.size,1)

In [161]: a[r] - a[c]
Out[161]: array([-2, -3, -1])

In [162]: a[0] - a[1]
Out[162]: -2

In [163]: a[0] - a[2]
Out[163]: -3

In [164]: a[1] - a[2]
Out[164]: -1
```